# How can i host my php and my reactjs project together to a server online

Tags: php, reactjs, hosting, web-hosting

If I used PHP as my backend and Reactjs as my frontend
Is it possible to host it to a single server online

Comment: it ought to be possible, yes. Where are you stuck?

Comment: On my localhost I used two ports one for reactjs and one for php so if I wanna host it do I need to used two Web server

Comment: No. Why would you? If your localhost can handle serving things on two different ports then so can any machine.

Comment: Thanks so much example if I hv the frontend to be www.example.com then the backend can be www.back.example.com am I right

Comment: you can configure subdomains, yes.